# can i use GPS and google maps on Android Tablet?

Tags: android, google-maps

I do not have an android tablet, and I do not know if I can use GPS and google maps with an android tablet, so for those who have android tablets, is it possible? and if possible does it work the same as android smartphones?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about GPS support on specific devices, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most tablets don't have GPS (massive generalisation), you would have to use some other provider to get the location (lat long). Like the Network Provider.

Yes you can use Google Maps on any google authenticated tablet.

---

If you use Google Play Services - Fusion Location Provider, you don't have to worry what providers the device has the library will do that for you:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: er yes it is. the Network Location Provider and GPS Location Provider are two distinct entities

Comment: you should go and google the acronym GPS, you are really using it in the wrong context. What you should have said is `i want to develop an application based on the users location and google maps, i want to test it on a tablet, is it possible?` the answer is YES

Comment: Google Play Services & the Fusion Location Provider https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. assuming given device features GPS receiver (most do have it anyway). But it would be better to use Fused Location Provider that combines more than one sources. See docs here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

The question is if you need just location or explicitely GPS provided location. In most cases you need just location, so Fused provider is a way to go as you do not need to bother if you are outdoor or indoor (where GPS is usually not working, but GSM/Wifi tirangulated location is working fine)

Comment: Most tablets do not have GPS. GPS has very poor performance in doors, and this is the main use case of tablets.